# How to monitor changes in a PostGIS database in GeoDjango?

Tags: qgis, geodjango, model, history

I have been working on a GeoDjango project which uses a PostGIS database.I have enabled the history in my application using the [django-simple-history](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module and works all fine.
The issues comes in when I edit a record using QGIS by using the PostGIS tool in QGIS. The changes I make using QGIS are not recorded in the history of the record. These include operations such as split features and merge (editing the geometry of the record).
First, is it the most ideal way of doing things in such a scenario?
Secondly, how do I ensure the changes in a record made through QGIS are tracked in the historical_model which can be visible in my GeoDjango application?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you can't without writing a lot of custom code.

When editing a PostGIS table through QGis, you are operating on the data in Postgres directly, and Django does not know anything about those changes.

As far as I know, the django package for history changes uses Python Code to log the changes in the history tables. So to make this work though QGis you would have to mimick this behavior by writing a QGis plugin or something like that. So for all I know this is not really possible without a lot of extra work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you yellowcap for the response.I have also been thinking about triggers that seem to have some sort of functionality that's can be cool. If I do a plugin,I agree it could be a lot.Any other workaround to such a  problem?